# Using Order By With Case Statement And Offset Fetch Together

Tags: sql, sql-server

I cant use Order By with Case Statement and Offset together in my stored procedure.

I get errors:

> Incorrect syntax near 'OFFSET'.

and

> Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement.

This is my code:

```
..
ORDER BY 
    CASE @OrderBy
        WHEN 'Phone' THEN u.[Phone]
        WHEN 'Name'  THEN u.[Name]
        ELSE u.[id] 
    END;
    OFFSET @Take * (@Page - 1) ROWS
    FETCH NEXT @Take ROWS ONLY
```

Is there any problem in my query? Or it's not possible at all, and I should try other methods like `ROW_NUMBER`?

Note that I'm using SQL Server 2016.

Thanks.

Comment: Remove `;` after `CASE .. END`

Comment: `;` is a statement terminator. it doesn't go in the middle of your statement, it goes at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ORDER BY with CASE, and you can also use expressions for the OFFSET / FETCH. There are plenty of examples in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

You did not provide your complete query, but from what you posted it seems that the issue is that the query termination semicolon is in the wrong place. It should be placed at the end of the query, after the ROWS ONLY. Otherwise, SQL Server tries to interpret your OFFSET statement as a query in its own right.

In addition, I highly recommend that you don't use variables for query logic. It is a recipe for bugs and performance challenges. It is better to write 3 queries, each with its own fixed ORDER BY and either have the application call each query separately depending on the ordering desired, or use flow control

```
IF @OrderBy = 'Phone' THEN <query order by phone>
ELSE IF @orderby = 'name' THEN <query order by name>
...
```

**1 Query for 1 task.**

HTH

Comment: I don't really agree this solves the problem, when the real problem is the `;` in the middle of the OP's query.

Comment: And I think you didn't read my answer, which explicitly states that the semicolon seems to be the issue :-) The rest is just bonus advice...